# What is the best camera to get that will give you a very nice photo on canvas print of 11 x 15 or larger?

Tags: printing, resolution, canvas-prints

I have tried several times to order a canvas print and it always comes back that the picture submitted will not work with the 11 x 15 canvas print and even an 8 X 10 wont work? I have a cannon E ( wont let me print name Santa's E )camera. What is the best type of camera I can buy that I can then make my pictures into Canvas photo's for my house? Just need the name of a good camera and know that it will turn into a wonderful Canvas photo.

Comment: It might be worth saying more about what camera you're currently using, and how you're editing and submitting your current photos for print. I'm surprised they are insufficient for 8x10. It makes me think you're downscaling them somewhere in the process. (That could be a separate question, if you don't want to confuse the issue here.)

Comment: I have no idea what "(wont let me print name Santa's E)" means, but I'm guessing it's an autocorrect error for "Series E". The only camera I know of in Canon's "E-for-entry-level" E Series is the [Powershot E1](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/digital_cameras/powershot_e_series/powershot_e1_white#Specifications), a 10 megapixel camera from 2008. In normal use, this produces images of 3648x2736 pixels, which is sufficient for up to 9x12 for anything requiring 300dpi. Canvas printers are often only 150dpi, so you should be okay up to 18x24". I think the problem isn't the camera.

Answer (score 1):

The key factor to making a good 11 by 15 print is having sufficient resolution.  For 11 by 15, 300ppi (pixels per inch) is ideal.  That means you need at least 3300 x 4500 pixel resolution.  That is a 15 megapixel image.  Any camera that produces decent quality images at 15 megapixels or better (and the correct aspect ratio) should work for producing an 11 by 15 print on whatever media type you choose.  You may need to go higher than 15 megapixels however to make sure that the vertical and horizontal pixel count is high enough, since the sensor may not match the same ratio as 11 by 15.